# Want to calculate difference from previous amount in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

Want to calculate difference from previous amount.

```
Order   EVENT NO    DATE    AMOUNT  EVENT AMOUNT(Difference of previous amount)
1   1         11/6/2020     100     100
1   2   11/6/2020           200     100
1   3   11/6/2020           500     300
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (amount - lag(amount, 1, 0) over (partition by order order by event_no)) as diff
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` function,

```
select order,  event_no, date, amount, 
case when 
(amount-LAG(amount) OVER (ORDER BY date, event_no)) is null then amount
else (amount-LAG(amount) OVER (ORDER BY date, event_no))
end as event_amount
from table;
```